# Can I clear the custom "status" without sending an empty broadcast to all my friends?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the *Friends* menu next to your status you can broadcast a message to your friends (send a pop-up in their game with your message). This message then sticks next to your status in order to indicate what you are up to in the game at the moment :

[image: Cropped screenshot of status/message block]

My issue is that when I want to erase this message, it seems I can only do it by first sending an empty one (that will send an empty pop-up to all my friends in game) which is kind of annoying :

[image: Cropped screenshot of message broadcast form]

- Clicking "OK" with an empty text send an empty pop-up (see image below)
- Clicking "CANCEL" cancels the edit and leave my previous custom status

[image: Cropped screenshot showing "Broadcast sent"]

How do I clear my custom status without sending an empty pop-up to my entire friendlist ?

Comment: Does it actually send an empty broadcast or does it just say it did to make the client logic easier?  I don't think I've ever gotten a notification with an empty message.

Comment: @Troyen I've recieved empty broadcastfrom my friends so I assume it does =)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is to type a message - There is no way to clear your status without it sending a message to your friends - it will always have a message attached.